# How to compare word segmentation methods?

Tags: natural-language-processing, unsupervised-learning, semantic-segmentation, perplexity

I am comparing a few methods of word segmentation in artificial language without dictionary and "golden" segmentation.
Let's say, `idolikecats` is splitted by three different algorithms to `i do like cats`, `ido li kecats` and `ido lik cat s`.

1. Is there a measure to compare the quality of the segmentation?
2. Is it a good idea to compare it with perplexity on the char level?
3. Would it require building an n-gram model for each segmentation method on the training set and comparing results from the test set?